# Theano.scan in hierarchical PyMC3 models

Tags: python, theano, bayesian, pymc3, hierarchical

I want to apply theano.scan over multiple parameters in a hierarchical model.

The code works great for a single model, however, I'm not sure how to convert the model to a hierarchical model (requiring additional looping).

Here is the code for the single model:

```
  with pm.Model() as bayesian_reinforcement_learning:

    # data
    actions_  = pm.Data('actions', actions)
    rewards_  = pm.Data('rewards', rewards)

    # priors
    alpha = pm.Beta('alpha', 1, 1)
    beta  = pm.HalfNormal('beta', 10)

    # model 
    # init Qs
    Qs = 0.3333 * tt.ones(3, dtype='float64')

    # Compute the Q values for each trial
    Qs, _ = theano.scan(
        fn=lambda action, reward, Qs, alpha: tt.set_subtensor(Qs[action], Qs[action] + alpha * (reward - Qs[action])),
        sequences=[actions_, rewards_],
        outputs_info=[Qs],
        non_sequences=[alpha])


    BQs = beta*Qs
    pi =  tt.nnet.softmax(BQs)
    like = pm.Categorical('like', p=pi, observed=actions_)

    # opt
    trace = pm.sample(tune=1000, chains=2, target_accept=0.85) # tune=5000, target_accept=0.9 njobs=4 ,target_accept=0.99
    idata = az.from_pymc3(trace)
    pm.traceplot(idata)
```

& here is the structure for the hierarchical model:

```
with pm.Model(coords=coords) as hierarchical_bayes_RL:

  # Data
  subject_idx = pm.Data("subject_idx", subject_idxs, dims="sub_id")

  # data
  actions_  = pm.Data('actions', df.actions.values)
  rewards_  = pm.Data('rewards', df.rewards.values)


  # Hyperpriors
  a_alpha = pm.HalfNormal("a_alpha", 5.0)
  b_alpha = pm.HalfNormal("b_alpha", 5.0)
  mu_b    = pm.HalfNormal('mu_b',   10.0)
  sigma_b = pm.HalfNormal("sigma_b", 5.0)
 

  # Intercept for each county, distributed around group mean mu_a
  # Above we just set mu and sd to a fixed value while here we
  # plug in a common group distribution for all a and b (which are
  # vectors of length n_counties).

  # parameters
  alpha = pm.Beta('alpha', a_alpha,  b_alpha, dims="subject")
  beta = pm.Normal("beta", mu=mu_b, sigma=sigma_b, dims="subject")


  # model 
  # init Qs

# 3 Qs values per parameter are required...?
  Qs = 0.3333 * tt.ones((3, 100), dtype='float64')


  # Compute the Q values for each trial
  # Qs, _ = theano.scan(
  #     # fn=lambda action, reward, Qs, alpha: Qs[action],
  #     fn = lambda action, reward, Qs, alpha: tt.set_subtensor(Qs[action], Qs[action] + alpha * (reward - Qs[action])),
  #     sequences=[actions_[subject_idx], rewards_[subject_idx]],
  #     outputs_info=[Qs],
  #     non_sequences=[alpha]
  # )
  


  BQs = beta[subject_idx]  * Qs[:, subject_idx]
  pi =  tt.nnet.softmax(BQs)
  like = pm.Categorical('P[A]', p=pi, observed=actions_, dims='sub_id')


pm.model_to_graphviz(hierarchical_bayes_RL)
```

If you have a better solution that is completely vectorized that would be awesome too! Anything that works, I'm new to theano...

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I grok what is happening here. Is this a recurrence equation? I.e., `Q_{n+1} = f(Q_{n}, reward_{n}, action_{n}, alpha)`. Perhaps it might help to describe the model (edit question).

Comment: Hi Merv!

Yes the recursion is part of the model. The first model works fine, however the second monday (where I attempt to convert the first mode to a hierarchical model) is invalid.. I'lm looking for assistance with making this conversion.